# Is it at all possible to get the Excalibur Prime frame if you did not participate in the Kickstarter?

Tags: warframe

One of my friends has been playing Warframe for a very long time, long enough that he has collected and maxed out every single frame, except for Excalibur Prime.

So, I know that Excalibur Prime was given out to the Kickstarters back when Warframe was starting out, but is there any way that one who did not participate in the funding be able to acquire Excalibur Prime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excalibur Prime was created as an exclusive frame and given to all players who participated in the Founders Program in the early days of warframe.

Unfortunately, Excal Prime was immediately discontinued, and will never be unvaulted. It is also untradable.

Comment: Additionally, someone recently pointed out to me that DE releasing any of the founders pack (Excalibur Prime, Skana Prime, Lato Prime) would actually be a breach of contract with the Founders.  ie, it will never never happen.